# How to set up timewarrior holidays

Tags: linux, arch-linux, to-do

I'm using taskwarrior with timewarrior and want to set up holidays. In the [documentation](https://taskwarrior.org/docs/timewarrior/tutorial.html#holidays) it says that the holiday files can be at `/usr/local/share/doc/timew/doc/holidays/holidays.en-US` but that the `path is platform-dependent, so use the appropriate path for your system.` 
On my system this path does not exist. I installed timew from the [community-repo](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/timew/)

How do I find out where the holiday files are located on my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for `timew` on the arch linux package search page: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/  On the timew package page, click view the file list near the bottom of the page.  It will show you all the files installed along with there default path.  It looks like the holidays.en-US file is installed at `/usr/share/doc/timew/doc/holidays/holidays.en-US`

You could also used the find command `find / -name holidays.en-US 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the holiday file for your locale doesn't exist, or is outdated.

Taskwarrior includes a script to generate these holiday files. On my system (Linux Mint), it can be found at `/usr/local/share/doc/task/scripts/add-ons/update-holidays.pl`. You can use it like this:

```
./update-holidays.pl --locale en-US --file holidays.en-US.rc
```